# Is Unix md5 different to python's hashlib.md5?

Tags: python, unix, hash, md5, hashlib

I run `echo lol | md5` in Mac Terminal and it returns: 
`59bcc3ad6775562f845953cf01624225`

But then I run `print hashlib.md5("lol").hexdigest()` in python 2.7 and I get:
`9cdfb439c7876e703e307864c9167a15`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`echo` appends a newline at the end by default, so it will give a different hash.

In python, with the newline ending

```
>>> print hashlib.md5("lol\n").hexdigest()
59bcc3ad6775562f845953cf01624225
```

Standard echo command, with the newline ending omitted.

```
$ echo -n lol | md5sum -
9cdfb439c7876e703e307864c9167a15  -
```